# In-chapter ToC formatting

Tags: tocloft

This code generates the following output:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titlecontents{psection}[2.3em]
    {\large}
    {\contentslabel{2.5em}}
    {}
    {\hspace*{.5em}\tikz[baseline]{\node[draw, inner sep=3pt, rounded corners, fill=red!30, anchor=base]{\thecontentspage};}}
    
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Sec1 I have title}
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{Sec2 Title goes here}
\lipsum[3-8]
\section{Sec3 Conditions goes here}
\lipsum[3-7]

\chapter{Chap2}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}

\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec1 This is a section}
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{Sec2 Final doc}
\lipsum[3-8]
\section{Sec3 Conditions goes here}
\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Problem is: I want the page numbers in the in-chapter contents appears in a line vertically equal. I have highlighted my need. The yellow marker shows the page number 3, 5 and 7 should appear in a straight line according to my choice about the distance. I can make it closer or far away.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a computer to try, but maybe try to add a \hfill before the drawing to push the drawing on the right, and adjust the distance with a negative space, something like \space{-2cm}

Comment: @tobiasBora Where do I put the commands? in `\titlecontents` or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `\hfill` and `\hspace{...}` you can do what you want (change the `hspace` value to put it closer or further from the right boundary):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titlecontents{psection}[2.3em]
    {\large}
    {\contentslabel{2.5em}}
    {}
    {\hfill\tikz[baseline]{\node[draw, inner sep=3pt, rounded corners, fill=red!30, anchor=base]{\thecontentspage};}\hspace*{4cm}}
    
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Sec1 I have title}
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{Sec2 Title goes here}
\lipsum[3-8]
\section{Sec3 Conditions goes here}
\lipsum[3-7]

\chapter{Chap2}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}

\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec1 This is a section}
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{Sec2 Final doc}
\lipsum[3-8]
\section{Sec3 Conditions goes here}
\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```